# Magento - Frontend router works locally but not on live server

Tags: magento, module, frontend, router

Ok so I have a very basic module setup. It's just a test module but essentially I should get "Here we are" displayed when I go to: http://www.mysite.com/vrmlookup/lookup/form.

The thing is that it works fine on my local machine (xampp) but I get a 404 when I try it on my live sever. It all looks fine to me and I'm utterly confused!

This is my module:

app/etc/modules/BlueDeep_MamVrm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <BlueDeep_MamVrm>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </BlueDeep_MamVrm>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/BlueDeep/MamVrm/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <BlueDeep_MamVrm>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </BlueDeep_MamVrm>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <vrmlookup>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>BlueDeep_MamVrm</module>
                    <frontName>vrmlookup</frontName>
                </args>
            </vrmlookup>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

app/code/local/BlueDeep/MamVrm/controllers/lookupController.php:

```
class BlueDeep_MamVrm_LookupController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function formAction()
    {
        die('Here we are');
    }
}
```

I'm pretty certain that all file permissions are correct and I have cleared all cache.

Any ideas?!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your controllers filename. It should be upper cased  (LookupController.php not lookupController.php). On Windows (xampp) it doesn't matter, but on a real server (a linux/unix one) filenames are case-sensitive. Magento development should be performed on a linux system, its easier that way (you don't have to track down strange errors - like this one). Try a virtual machine as a server, and access your file via Samba. I work that way, and it doesn't make any problems.

When your Magento MySQL server is running on Windows, you could suffer from very big response times (especially while reindexing). Using a virtual machine, lets you to use your favorite Windows tools and test your app in an environment close to the production one.

Comment: Ahhh fun with windows! Thanks for that. After this I may just set up a virtual machine as you suggest.

Comment: I find that using a shared folder is better than Samba.  It makes it dead simple to have a single VM for Magento work and keep the web root , DB data files, and Logs in a shared folder and external to the VM.  This allows me to swap out the shared folders and change projects without any change to the VM OS.

Comment: I use samba share, and mount it as a web drive on Windows. Eclipse can use it as its project base. Also I can mount my VM as Eclipse Remote System with a terminal and a tail -f on a log file. There is one downside of a Samba Share - repositories. Its quite tricky to create a SVN/GIT Repo on this kind of filesystem (even through a webdrive).

Comment: I have now set up a VM running CentOS with Samba share and I have it mapped within windows. This allows my Eclipse to use it as a project base like you suggest. So far so good! Thanks